# APNS: How to get the Error response after sending?

Tags: php, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push

I want to send Push Notifications with PHP.

So I set up some code to send them. It actually works well but now I have to do some error handling.

If I e.g. post an invalid token to Apple and then send some valid tokens, Apple won't push the message to the valid token's device.

So I will check the Stream after every time I sent a payload for an response which will tell me, if there were any issues.

```
$test = fwrite($this->fp, $payload);

if ($test != strlen($payload)) {
    echo 'NOT ALL BYTES WRITTEN'; //This is just for debug
}

usleep(1000000); //Wait for Apple to respond.

$error_hex = fread($this->fp, 6);
if ($error_hex !== false && strlen($error_hex) == 6) {
    $error = unpack('Ccommand/Cstatus_code/Nidentifier', $error_hex);

    print_r($error);
} else {
    echo 'NO HEX ERROR';
}
```

This always outputs "NO HEX ERROR", so Apple didn't respond with an error.

Why does this not work?
Stream Blocking is disabled.

```
stream_set_blocking($this->fp, 0);
```

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? I'm still not receiving errors, even if replacing the tokens with `lalelu`...

Answer (score 0):

Invalid token, not mean it is "NO EXIST TOKEN", it mean that token is in sandbox enviment, you send token of sandbox for production, cause Invalid Token